# Retraining OPENCV Cascade Classifier in python using pretrained XML file over new training data

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, cascade-classifier

So I want to train a Open-CV cascade classifier to detect frontal-faces though i want to do it in IR modal. Is there a way I could use the opencv provided xml file for frontal faces from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) and train it on my new images to improive the classifier. So my question is can I reuse the cascade classifier (in XML file) to train over new set of images in Python?

Comment: with the opencv tools you would at least need the `stages folders` of the original classifier. Not sure whether changin the training samples is possible.

Comment: The .xml you have is the result of a previous training process. You need to perform your own according to the steps in https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html. You can find a very useful step by step here: https://medium.com/@dikshitkathuria1803/training-your-own-cascade-classifier-detector-opencv-9ea6055242c2